# How to add a common string in every randomly generated string Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, random

I am generating random strings using the below function in node.js. I wanted to know if there is any way to create text strings appropriately with a *common string* within every randomly generated string.

EDIT: The common string can be in any location of the generated string

*For example:*

Randomly generated string - ***Cxqtooxyy4***

Can I add ***'abc'***  or ***'ABC'*** within that string like this - ***Cxqtoabcoxyy4*** or ***CxqtoABCoxyy4*** respectively.

My Code -

```
var randomTextArrayGeneration = function(size)
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for(var i=0;i<size;i++)
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    return text;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how do I do this? Any help is really helpful.

Comment: Should the common string always be at the same position within the random string? What if the `size` specified is shorter than the common string?

Comment: A little unclear about your requirements. Does the embedded string need to be in the same location each time? Does it need to be in a random location each time? Does it not matter where it is?

Comment: Sorry didn't explain it properly. The embedded string can be in any location.

Comment: Can you...yes, of course. Shouldn't be hard to get an idea how by looking at the various substring/manipulation methods that are documented in numerous places on web and at least making an attempt

Comment: *Any* location? Then why not just place it at the end after generating a random string with length size -3 (assuming the fixed string is of length 3).

Comment: What is expected result if `size` is `2` or `3`?

Comment: Thank You all for the suggestions and answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var n = text.length; //The size of your random string
var randomPosition = Math.floor((Math.random() * n) + 1); //Generate a  random number between 1 and the size of your string

//Separate your string in 2 strings
var text1 = text.substring(1, randomPosition); 
var text2 = text.substring(randomPosition, n); 

//Create your final string by adding the common string between your two halves
var textFinal = text1 + commonString + text2;

return textFinal;
```

I don't remember how exactly works `.substring()`, you may want to change 1 by 0 in some places.

Answer (score 1):

A rough sketch of the algorithm is this:

1. create random string of length `size - <FIXED_STRING>.length`
2. append `<FIXED_STRING>` to the end of generated string

Done.

A corner case is if `size < <FIXED_STRING>.length`, here you would need to provide some more discussion on what should happen.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) It gave me an idea I could try it on my own as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.slice()` to select 0-n characters from `possible` to insert into random index within string returned from `randomTextArrayGeneration`. If `0` is passed to `randomTextArrayGeneration` the selected string from `possible` will be set as result

```
var randomTextArrayGeneration = function(size, from, to) {
      var text = "";
      var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
      for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length))
      };
      var len = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length - 3);
      var res = text.slice(0, len) + possible.slice(from, to).toLowerCase() + text.slice(len);
      return res
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)